# Two windows installed but there is no boot manager

Tags: windows-xp, multi-boot

A Windows XP has been installed in C: however I have installed another windows XP on D:
The problem is that as I power on the computer, it goes directly to the old windows!

There is no boot manager which let me choose the right one. Now in C: there are windows and program files folders for the old windows XP and in D: there are windows and program files for the new one.

How can I manually edit the boot manager? I think this should be done via msconfig->boot but I can not see any edit button for that.

Comment: You will need to modify the boot loader.  There are hundreds of tutorials that exist that explain how to do this.

Comment: Can you give me a working guide? My search reveals windows XP and 7 dual boot!

Comment: BCD Edit is one such program.

Comment: @Ramhound: What good is BCDEdit for setting up dual boot between two instances of XP?

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if msconfig->boot will work as they are installed on separate hard drives.

What I believe you want to do is change boot devices. To do so you will need to use the BIOS, when booting early on it will say something like "Press F10 for Boot List" or "Press F9 for Bios Menu". You will want to press what it tells you too

When the menu loads, look around for where you select the boot device and select the hard drive that has the new version of Windows XP

Comment: I don't understand the relation between BIOS settings and two windows on the same HDD. If you mean that I have to change the boot priority (CD and HDD) then that is not problem

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest first to backup `boot.ini` file and then follow this instructions.

- Click Start, click Run, type sysdm.cpl, and then click OK.
- On the Advanced tab, click Settings under `Startup and Recovery`.
- Under System Startup, click `Edit`.

According to your situation it may look like

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Windows XP Professional" /fastdetect
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS="Windows XP Professional" /fastdetect
```

Now you might be getting idea how to change a default OS.

- Just Edit 3rd line (as in above) to `default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS`.

We are just changing the partition number. In this case it is 2. It might be different in your case and then `Save`.

Comment: Sounds like you installed the second copy with the first drive disconnected. If that is so this may be the simplest solution - as long as the second copy sees its drive letter to be same as when it was installed.